# 特定の期間が与えられた際に、月毎にグループ分けを行いたい

Tags: python, python3

pythonで特定の期間（start, end）が与えられた際に、月毎にグループ分けを行いたいです。
具体的には、1/15 - 3/3という期間が与えられた場合には、
1/15 - 1/31, 2/1 - 2/28, 3/1 - 3/3という形でグループ分けしたいです。

とりあえず下記のコードで実現はできましたが、下記の2点から良い方法、シンプルな方法があるのではないかと考えております。

1. グループ分けを行える関数がありそう（itertools.groupbyをうまくつかう？）
2. 前月の最終日を求める所が冗長

改善点等ありましたら教えてください。

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, date
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
def hoge(start, end):
    def _hoge(l, s, e):
        one_month_after = s + relativedelta(months=1)
        next_month = date(one_month_after.year, one_month_after.month, 1)
        month_last_day = next_month - timedelta(days=1)
        if e <= month_last_day:
            l.append((s, e))
            return l
        l.append((s, month_last_day))
        return _hoge(l, next_month, e)
    return _hoge([], start, end)

hoge(date(2019, 1, 15), date(2019, 3, 3))
```

出力

```
# [(datetime.date(2019, 1, 15), datetime.date(2019, 1, 31)),
#  (datetime.date(2019, 2, 1), datetime.date(2019, 2, 28)),
#  (datetime.date(2019, 3, 1), datetime.date(2019, 3, 3))]
```

Comment: 初めて知りましたが [calendar](https://docs.python.org/3/library/calendar.html) というモジュールがあり，[`calendar.monthrange`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/calendar.html#calendar.monthrange) が使えそうです ([本家の質問](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42950/get-last-day-of-the-month-in-python))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`itertools.groupby()` を使うとすれば以下の様になります。

```
from datetime import date, timedelta
from itertools import groupby

def hoge(start, end):
  return [(d[0], d[-1]) for d in [list(v) for _, v in groupby(
    [start + timedelta(days=x) for x in range(0, (end-start).days+1)],
    key = lambda x: (x.year, x.month))]]

hoge(date(2019, 1, 15), date(2019, 3, 3))
```

pandas を使うと簡潔になるかもしれません。

ところで、

```
hoge(date(2019, 1, 31), date(2019, 3, 1))
```

とすると、結果は以下の様になるのですが、これはこれでよろしいのでしょうか？

```
[(datetime.date(2019, 1, 31), datetime.date(2019, 1, 31)),
 (datetime.date(2019, 2, 1), datetime.date(2019, 2, 28)),
 (datetime.date(2019, 3, 1), datetime.date(2019, 3, 1))]
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。結果については月毎になっておりますので想定通りになります。ただ、groupby使ってもちょっとシンプルとはいいがたい感じですね。pandasで簡潔になるのであれば使ってみたいと思います。

Answer (score 1):

愚直な方法ですが、開始日から終了日まで datetime オブジェクトを１日ごとに作成、groupby で月単位でグループにわけ、そのグループの最小値と最大値を求めることで所望の結果が得られます。行っていることは @metropolis さんのものとほぼ同じで、インデックスの代わりに min, max 関数を使用している分遅いのですが、可読性が上がったのかは微妙なところです。

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from itertools import groupby

def hoge(start, end):
    # datetime(start) から datetime(end) までの１日ごとに datetime オブジェクトのリストを作成
    d = start
    d_lst = []
    while d <= end:
        d_lst.append(d)
        d += timedelta(1)
    # 月単位でグループにわけ、そのグループ内の要素の最小と最大を求める
    out = []
    for k, g in groupby(d_lst, lambda d: d.month):
        g = list(g)
        s = min(g)
        e = max(g)
        out.append([s, e])
    return out

start = datetime(2019,1,15)
end = datetime(2019,3,1)
out = hoge(start, end)
print(out)

# Out: [[datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 15, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 31, 0, 0)],
#       [datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 1, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 28, 0, 0)],
#       [datetime.datetime(2019, 3, 1, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2019, 3, 1, 0, 0)]]
```

pandas は勉強中のため詳しくないのですが、上記の処理を pandas で実装してみました。参考になれば幸いです。また、pandas は勉強中ですので、改善点等ご指摘いただけたら幸いです。

```
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd

start = datetime(2019,1,15)
end = datetime(2019,3,1)

ds = pd.date_range(start, end).to_series()
out = [i for i in zip(ds.groupby(ds.dt.month).min(), ds.groupby(ds.dt.month).max())]
print(out)
# Out: [(Timestamp('2019-01-15 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2019-01-31 00:00:00')),
#       (Timestamp('2019-02-01 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2019-02-28 00:00:00')),
#       (Timestamp('2019-03-01 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2019-03-01 00:00:00'))]
```